# Dont see how to change age rating / usage on app submission

Tags: xcode

Hello I am trying to submit my first App to the Apple App Store using and it says "A few more items are needed in order to submit for review
The items listed below are required for submission:
You must select the level of frequency for each Apple content description in the Age Rating section."

I don't have an age ratting. I also dont see a part on the website to change the level of frequency. does anyone know where to change this?

Comment: So this is about how to use a web site?

Answer (score 52):

**Update 07/12/2021**

As *user3094434* states in the comment below, the information has now been moved to "General" > "App Information" > "General Information" from the menu on the left side.

**Old Answer**

In the tab App Store where you enter app information, you should be able to find it.

It is located under **General App Information** (containing both the **App Store Icon** and **Version** section) there should be an **Age Rating** you can click edit on.

[image: Section to find]

When you click the edit button you will be prompted with the following window:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The confusing part was that "App Information" also has Age Rating but no Edit button. Instead you have to edit via the Prepare For Submission page

Comment: Yeh, that Edit button is hard to find!

Comment: The age rating won't change for us, even when we press edit :-/ our app can't be released at the moment we're in a limbo.

Comment: I am trying to submit an update of the app. And although i have changed the age rating to 17+ from the app information page. The app still got rejected saying that the age rating 12+ is wrong. Now the steps provided by them says to update the age rating from the version page as shown in the above answer but while submitting an update there is no such option. Please help.

Comment: it's now in different page/tab, in General->App Information under the section General Information. small title: Age Rating

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to above answer if you won't find the App Rating as editable or edit button is not showing up on app rating.
Just go to Prepare for Submission Page at the left handside of the page at the top.
On that page scroll down. There you will find App rating with edit button.